# Detect whether project is being compiled for windows 8 or wp

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-8, c-preprocessor

I have a windows phone app and I am trying to port it to windows 8. The problem is that several classes should be common among these projects. But some features from windows phone don't work on windows 8 and vice versa. So I should probably use preprocessor derectives for detecting OS. Are there any already defined preprocessor constants that could help me with that? Or could you suggest some better way for doing that?

P.S. These classes use async ctp library. And also some of them have networking capabilities. And as loading files in wp and win8 are implemented in different ways (I need asynchronous file downloading with custom headers and POST requests), I also have to take that into account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best option is to put all common code in a [Portable Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx). This will allow you to target multiple platforms.

I think there is not preprocessor directive for windows 8 but you can easily create a new one in a build configuration (properties/condition compilation symbols).

Comment: Is there any other way? Because I am using async ctp library which Portable Class Library does not support.

Comment: No. The Async CTP has different dlls for Desktop, Phone, Silverlight 4, and Silverlight 5. Async is just a new syntax. You can do the same with portable library.

Comment: And I don't seem to make it out: how do I use Async CTP with portable class library in vs2010? When compiling, it gives me the following error: `The primary reference "AsyncCtpLibrary" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0 ..." which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETPortable,Version=v4.0,Profile=Profile104". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "AsyncCtpLibrary" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0...".`