# Macro for Windows Store App support

Tags: windows-8, static-libraries, porting, windows-store-apps

i have a library developed in C . I am porting it ,for Windows Store App support. For it i have enabled the Option **YES** for **WindowsStoreAppSupport** setting in project settings->configuration properties ->General tab .

Now i have to write code for both the settings where there is windowsstore app support and no support.
can any one let me know what Macro i need to use if i have to know WindowsStoreAppSupport is YES/NO from the settings to use in the code for conditional compilation? i have to support all win32/x64 and ARM configurations.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576649/detect-whether-project-is-being-compiled-for-windows-8-or-wp), you could use a build configuration symbol to determine what you're targeting.